# DevExpress GridControl : Checkedit on Column Trouble

Tags: vb.net, devexpress-gridcontrol

I try to make grid columns during runtime, and one of column using repositorycheckedit, I tried several methods but none worked

here is my code

```
Dim dtSet As New DataSet()
        Dim dtTable As New DataTable("menu")
        Dim grCol As New DataColumn
        Dim rpChk As New RepositoryItemCheckEdit

        grCol.ColumnName = "smenu"
        grCol.Caption = "Menu"
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Menu")
        dtTable.Columns(0).ColumnName = "smenu"
        dtTable.Columns.Add("New")
        dtTable.Columns(1).ColumnName = "snew"

        dtTable.Rows.Add("Nama", 1)

        dtSet.Tables.Add(dtTable)

        gr.DataSource = dtSet
        gr.DataMember = "menu"

        rpChk.ValueChecked = 1
        rpChk.ValueUnchecked = 0
        grV.Columns("snew").ColumnEdit = rpChk
```

somehow, the column supposed to show checkbox always grayed out, if i try to mark the checkbox, it will become null after lost focus/change cell

pplease anyone.? thanks

Source #2 (After revised) and still no result as expected

```
Dim dtTable As New DataTable("menu")
Dim rpChk As New RepositoryItemCheckEdit

dtTable.Columns.Add("Menu")
dtTable.Columns(0).ColumnName = "smenu"
dtTable.Columns.Add("New")
dtTable.Columns(1).ColumnName = "snew"

dtTable.Rows.Add("Nama", CSByte(1))
dtTable.Rows.Add("Nama1", CSByte(0))
dtTable.Rows.Add("Nama2", CSByte(1))
dtTable.Rows.Add("Nama3", CSByte(0))

gr.DataSource = dtTable

rpChk.ValueChecked = 1
rpChk.ValueUnchecked = 0

grV.Columns("snew").ColumnEdit = rpChk
```

Comment: This is likely not related to your issue but what is the `DataSet` for? Just create the `DataTable` and assign that directly to the `DataSource`. I don;t use that particular grid control but you can do it that way with a `DataGridView` so I suspect that this one is the same. Don't create a `DataSet` where a `DataTable` alone will do the job.

Comment: Also, your code makes little sense where you create/add the columns to the table. You create a `DataColumn` and set its `ColumnName` and `Caption` but then you never use it. You then add two columns with names but then immediately discard that name and set their `ColumnName` directly. That part is all over the place. Just create the table and then call `Columns.Add` twice, specifying a name and data type. If you want to set the `Caption` too then chain that on the end, e.g. `table.Columns.Add("FullName", GetType(String)).Caption = "Full Name"`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you, that is correct, just realized you can just ignore dataset and create table using datatable. Now I revised a little my code, but still the checkedit won't work as expected.. (still grayed out)

Answer (score 0):

After tried several times, maybe someone needs answer
So finally I solved it. When create columns we need to define what type for the columns

```
dtTable.Columns.Add("Menu",GetType(String))
dtTable.Columns(0).ColumnName = "smenu"
dtTable.Columns.Add("New",GetType(Boolean))
dtTable.Columns(1).ColumnName = "snew"
```

And things finally worked.